# Rotate Line around a pivot? SceneBuilder JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

it's possible to rotate a line not in center but on a different pivot with SceneBuilder, if it's possible how? thanks for help.

im using this code for now but the pivot is on the center:

```
@FXML
private Line lancettaQuadroCentrale;

@FXML

private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");        
        RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(4),lancettaQuadroCentrale);
        rt.setByAngle(0);
        rt.setToAngle(220);
        rt.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            rt.setAutoReverse(true);
        rt.play();
    }
```

Comment: See this [rotation transform demo app](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1475424), perhaps the concepts illustrated there will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Timeline` to animate the `angle` property of [a `Rotate` transform](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) applied to the `Line`:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction() {
    System.out.println("You clicked me!");

    Rotate rotate = new Rotate(0, pivotX, pivotY);

    lancettaQuadroCentrale.getTransforms().add(rotate);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 0d)),
                                     new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(4), new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), 220d)));      

    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);

    timeline.play();
}
```

Comment: hi, netbeans report this error "KeyValue is abstract, cannot be instantiated"  on timeline row

Comment: solved with import of javafx.animation.KeyValue; but give me a strange rotation not a normal translation :P

Comment: @FrancescoValla Could you describe the difference to the expected result? How does the hierarchy look (are you e.g. using `Group` as parent)?

Answer (score 0):

Set axis of `RotateTransition`:

`rt.setAxis(new Point3D(10, 0, 0));`